# two mutually attracted particles in 1D space

Tags: particle-physics

I'm wondering - can two particles under attractive force ever come to full stop in 1D space? Or will they oscillate for an infinitely long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your particles are ideal, that is they have no internal degrees of freedom, then they cannot come to a mutual stop because this would violate the conservation of energy. In the real world colliding bodies can come to a stop because they transfer their kinetic energy into internal degrees of freedom (typically heat). Without some way to dissipate energy or transfer it away your particles will oscillate indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for answer! No internal degrees (precisely - no colliding). If this `F=G*m1*m2/r^2` is the formula for force between the particles, how do I deal with `r=0`?

Comment: For ideal particles, r = 0 is bad. You can't really calculate what goes on here. For real particles, their finite radius prevents them from coming closer than the sum of their radii. In N-body simulations, which treat bodies as point sources, you usually use a so-called _gravity_ _softening_  _length_ ε, which defines the smallest scales that your simulation can resolve. Forces are then calculated as `F = G m1 m2 / (r^2 + ε^2)`.

Comment: @pela So, does it mean there are no way of describing overlapping ideal particles? Is this the case with any known field (gravitational, electromagnetic, etc.)?

Comment: @ikaruss: Not in regular Newtonian gravity. If your particles are really point-like, they will be smaller than their Schwarschild radius, i.e. they will be black holes, so when they come close enough, they will merge to form a larger BH. Quantum mechanically, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle will prevent them from having zero extension (unless they have infinite momentum). If you mean numerically, then the finite step size of the distance will mean that they could pass each other without F going to infinity, but that's just a numerical artefact.

Comment: This is true for all fields where forces have r in the denominator. There's no way to handle an infinite force.

Comment: @pela If the particles are indeed black holes and merge once close enough, does the resulting black hole contains energy of both particles plus the initial potential energy between them? I guess, that would be the full stop, no further oscillation.

Comment: My knowledge of GR is rather limited, and I'm unsure if some of the energy may be radiated away, but they would definitely come to a stop, since nothing can leave a BH after having crossed the horizon.

Comment: @pela Thank you for sharing knowledge you have! :)

Comment: You're are very welcome :)